# Net6 - project always run in Development, despite --environment Production

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

My question is just, how is this result (below) possible?

No matter what I put after --environment, whether in quotes or not, my dotnet 6 project here, always runs in Development.
Is it because projects that have to be compiled based on source code are forced to run in Development mode or some other knowledge I'm missing?

```
$ dotnet run --environment Production
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:5002
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
```

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet run -- --environment Production`? (The extra `--` are no accident)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [dotnet run documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run), there is no such thing as an `--environment` switch.  Maybe what you want is `--launch-profile`.

In any case, that output stating the hosting environment comes from the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.  See the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables).

### UPDATE

The OP commented with a link that is misleading.  The `dotnet run` command does **not** come with an `--environment` switch.  This is passed as an argument to the application being run, and it is the application's responsibility to do anything (or nothing) with it.

#### dotnet Information

The following is the result of running `dotnet --info` in my PC:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.400
 Commit:    7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.10
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5a400c212a

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

So pretty much up-to-date.  Now this is the result of running `dotnet run --help`:

```
Description:
  .NET Run Command

Usage:
  dotnet run [options] [[--] <additional arguments>...]]

Options:
  -c, --configuration <CONFIGURATION>  The configuration to run for. The default for most projects is 'Debug'.
  -f, --framework <FRAMEWORK>          The target framework to run for. The target framework must also be specified in the project file.
  -r, --runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>   The target runtime to run for.
  --project <project>                  The path to the project file to run (defaults to the current directory if there is only one project).
  -p, --property <property>            Properties to be passed to MSBuild.
  --launch-profile <launch-profile>    The name of the launch profile (if any) to use when launching the application.
  --no-launch-profile                  Do not attempt to use launchSettings.json to configure the application.
  --no-build                           Do not build the project before running. Implies --no-restore.
  --interactive                        Allows the command to stop and wait for user input or action (for example to complete authentication).
  --no-restore                         Do not restore the project before building.
  --sc, --self-contained               Publish the .NET runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine.
                                       The default is 'true' if a runtime identifier is specified.
  --no-self-contained                  Publish your application as a framework dependent application. A compatible .NET runtime must be installed on the target machine to run your application.
  -v, --verbosity <LEVEL>              Set the MSBuild verbosity level. Allowed values are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic].
  -a, --arch <arch>                    The target architecture.
  --os <os>                            The target operating system.
  -?, -h, --help                       Show command line help.

Additional Arguments:
  Arguments passed to the application that is being run.
```

This confirms my original statement:  The `dotnet` does not provide any `--environment` switch.

So why the documentation linked by the user, which is a Microsoft-provided page, recommends its use?  Well, it is assuming you have the [Command-Line Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#command-line) set up as part of your configuration providers.

If you have deviated from the [default application configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-application-configuration-sources) and effectively removed the command-line provider (or moved it to a position that gets overridden by another provider, like the environment variable provider), then you lose the ability to set the environment using the `--environment` switch.

Comment: That may be old documentation, it references .Net3.1- this Net6 documentation uses the command line I'm referring to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-environment-on-the-command-line

Comment: @PandaWood I updated my answer to account for the provided URL.

Comment: Thanks @José Ramírez - I didn't think I'd deviated in my fairly basic project, but it will be up to me to prove that now, very interesting