Why does 'dotnet run' always run my project in Development mode?
I'm trying to run my .net 8 service on Windows 10x64 22H2 via
dotnet run --environment Test

or
dotnet run --environment Production

but it always prints:
Hosting environment: Development

What should I do to enforce the service use the specific environment?

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34799

To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:
1)DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
2)ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when the WebApplication.CreateBuilder method is called.The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call WebApplication.CreateBuilder. The DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT value overrides ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when WebApplicationBuilder is used. For other hosts, such as ConfigureWebHostDefaults and WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder, ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has higher precedence.
Reffer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Note:
Production is the default value if DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT have not been set. Apps deployed to Azure are Production by default.
Environment values in launchSettings.json override values set in the system environment.
To set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
dotnet run --no-launch-profile

For Mac:
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
dotnet run --no-launch-profile


The OP is not using asp.net

@ramshankar-tv does it mean that 'dotnet run' does not support --environment cmd line parameter?

It does support which is mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-environment-on-the-command-line.  Although I can't pin point the issue, I give an idea how ASP.NET Core determine the runtime environment and Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216135/net6-project-always-run-in-development-despite-environment-production

Ok, but per your first link it looks like the 'dotnet' tool should support the specified environment, but it's not quite clear what takes precedence - environment from cmd line or environment from ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Is it working with no launch profile by setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
?
